# MVC password not working after reset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a Reset Password reset option in my website. When creating a account I hash my password like this: `Password = Hasher.Hash(username + unhashedPassword);` in the constructor, With my Reset Password option I can already succesfully place a new hashed password in the database upon confirmation with the PasswordToken, but I don't understand if I hash the new password and place it in the database why I cannot login with the new password I set

Reset Password HttpGet:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string Id)
    {
        Id = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        ResetPassword model = new ResetPassword();
        model.PasswordToken = Id;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Reset Password HttpPost:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPassword model)
    {
        if (Repository.ChangePassword(model.PasswordToken, model.Password))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("PasswordResetSuccess");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("PasswordResetFailure");
    }
```

Reset Password View:

```
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, "New Password:")
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepeatPassword, "Repeat Password:")
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RepeatPassword)
```

DatabaseHandler ChangePassword method:

```
public static bool ChangePassword(string passwordToken, string password)
    {
        RecipeDbContext ctx = new RecipeDbContext();
        Account foundPassword = ctx.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(u => u.PasswordToken == passwordToken);
        if(foundPassword != null)
        {
            password = Hasher.Hash(foundPassword.Username + foundPassword.Password);
            DbSet<Account> dbSet = ctx.Set<Account>();
            dbSet.Attach(foundPassword);
            ctx.Entry(foundPassword).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Repository ChangePassword method:

```
public static bool ChangePassword(string paswordToken, string password)
    {
        return DatabaseHandler.ChangePassword(passwordToken, password);
    }
```

Hasher Class:

```
public class Hasher
{
    public static string Hash(string text)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(text)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by using this order:

```
string hashedPassword = Hasher.Hash(foundPassword.Username + password);
foundPassword.Password = hashedPassword;
```